# How to read .txt file with condition

Tags: c++, struct

My application is quite simple but still a bit of code so I just break it down. For example my text file look like this

```
John Doe
British
2
Swimming test
Soccer
```

My structure is quite basic:

```
string name;
char national [MAX];
int noOfHobbies;
char hobby [MAXNO][MAX];
```

Then I have a function to open this file in order to read the data and successfully manage to read it, but the problem is that it does not output "Soccer" as the second hobby but "test". My function basically look something like this:

```
................................

const int MAXRECS=10;
MyInfo infoList[MAXRECS];
while( getline(afile, line) ) {
    MyInfo temp; // MyInfo is a structure
    temp.name = line; 
    afile >> temp.national;
    afile >> temp.noOfWishes;
    for(int j = 1; j <= temp.noOfWishes; j++) {
        afile >> temp.wish[j];
    }
}

..............................................
cout << "I have " <<  infoList[i].noOfHobbies<< " hobbies" << endl; // output "I have 2 hobbies"
for(int j = 1; j <= infoList[i].noOfHobbies; j++) {
        cout << j << ": " << infoList[i].hobby[j] << '\n'; // output "Swimming" and "Test"
}
```

Why is it read space as a new line here since it's working fine for `name` and `national` but not `hobby`? I'm new to C++ so hopefully you can sympathize for me if this is a basic question.

Comment: You really should be using `std::string` and `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays and arrays of chars. You've got all kinds of buffer-overflow problems waiting to happen here. Effective C++ requires being familiar the [Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) or you'll waste your time re-inventing things and usually doing it badly. Also shouldn't you have a `struct` or `class` which represents each entry instead of a pile of unrelated variables?

Comment: Arrays are indexed from 0. In your for loops, your initializer should be `j=0` and your end condition should be `j < [var].noOfHobbies`.  Also, you seem to be using `noOfWishes` and `noOfHobbies` interchangeably. Please stick to one, unless they are actually different fields (and same with `hobby` and `wish`.